# How to design an app for changing CSS file for website from given URL?

Tags: html, css, spring, architecture

I want to make an app which will be working similar to Stylish extension and google chrome inspector. Is it possible to make something like this but working not as an extension but as a separate service?

I've already done client app based on react which have menu with elements to change, for example I can choose font type, font size, colors, etc.
Beside menu, I have iframe which displays site from url - my idea was to download whole webpage on the server side, deploy it with docker on nginx to serve it and send back my new url to the client. Is there any easier way to do it?

I've also done simple backend app based on spring which downloads the whole webpage to folder.
The most important thing in this app is to generate separate CSS file which can be later included to given webpage.

I struggle with few problems:

1. How to display website from url, if with iframe, how to change CSS of given website?
2. How to display changed CSS immediately?

How you got any ideas or tips how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using javascript you can apply your changes to the layout and save it as 'actions' to perform after rendering,,,, or you could generate own css and based on that css generete functions, which perform the change to the layout ( the other way around )

Answer (score 0):

To swop the stylesheet, give the link element an id so you can reference it, then reset its href, i.e.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/default.css" id="themeStyles" />
```

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
  let stylesheetUrl = 'style/' + themeName + '.css';
  document.getElementById('themeStyles').setAttribute("href", stylesheetUrl);
}
```

If the page hosted in the iframe is served from the same domain as the iframe then this is easily done with cross frame scripting.